# 'de qui': 'whose' or 'from whom' in this sentence?

Tags: prépositions, pronoms

This is the last sentence from Mirbeau's story 'Paysage de foule' (1900):

> Alors,   seulement   la   dame,   toute   frémissante,   remonta dans sa voiture, poursuivie par les huées de  cette  foule  aux  griffes  et  aux  crocs  de  qui  les  petits doigts d’une femme venaient d’arracher un peu de chair humaine.

I am not sure how to understand the 'de qui'. Does it mean '**whose** little lady's fingers had just torn out a bit of human flesh' or '**from whom** a lady's little fingers had just torn a bit of human flesh'?

Comment: I don't understand either what the author exactly means. From the context of the scene, the only one that was hurt is the beggar that has stolen the lady's bag.

Comment: After some thinking (before having read the nice @segorian answer), I believe that the "bit of human flesh" was the beggar that she protected from angry mob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*From whose*" is the translation. This can be seen more easily after a drastic simplification of the sentence.

- La dame était poursuivie par une foule aux griffes de qui elle venait d’arracher un peu de chair.
- The lady was pursued by a crowd from whose claws she had just wrenched some flesh.

---

*Addition due to a comment by [user Frank](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1387/frank)*

I/ Remarque très juste en ce qui concerne la forme du pronom relatif. J'aurais dû faire cette remarque moi-même. Pour une personne c'est plutôt  « qui » ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23508/la-grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-relatifs/le-pronom-relatif-lequel-et-les-formes-contractees-duquel-et-auquel), mais les noms qui ne sont pas ceux qui représentent une personne il n'y a pas d'alternative (« qui » ne va pas). Une foule, cependant, ne consiste  que de personnes, et bien que je ne connaisse pas de règle de «  notional agreement » en français, voilà un cas où on pourrait peut-être faire référence à ce concept. La raison de cela ce sont des possibilités comme les suivantes : « ce malfaiteur aux griffes de qui elle venait d’arracher le sac volé », « ces gens aux griffes de qui elle venait d’arracher le sac volé ». Voilà par exemple des [cas d'utilisation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gens%20%C3%A0%20qui%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) de « à qui » pour « gens » (et non « auxquels »). Il s'ensuit que la notion de  « personne » reste très dominante, tout aussi dominante que pour « foule ». Il y a bien sûr une nuance, « gens » est un pluriel, mais rien d'autre ne vient contrarier cette notion. Je me demande donc si « qui » ne serait pas, au moins marginalement, acceptable.

II/ As you say, the « XquelY» pronoun would be better; at least, I also think so : as you say, it wouldn't raise any eyebrow. However, to get back again to this concept of notional agreement, which is largely unknown in French grammar, I wouldn't apply it here in any case and I'd use « de laquelle ». For instance you'll never find French sentences such as « La foule étaient parti(e)s. ».

- Alors, seulement la dame, toute frémissante, remonta dans sa voiture, poursuivie par les huées de cette foule aux griffes et aux crocs de laquelle les petits doigts d’une femme venaient d’arracher un peu de chair humaine.

(Note        I hope the reader won't mind the switching from one language to the other; although not too far advanced in the French part of the text when realizing this discontinuity, I felt bad at the idea of plowing through a translation.)

Comment: Yes, but, un peu de chair humaine vient d'être arrachée, par les petits doigts d'une famme, des griffes et des crocs de cette foule. So, I think "de qui" is not entirely correct, because "griffes and crocs" are not a person, but "qui" would be approprivate for a _person_. I think the following is better, and doesn't raise any eyebrow: "poursuivie par les huées de cette foule aux griffes et aux crocs desquels les petits doigts d’une femme venaient d’arracher un peu de chair humaine."

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I feel that "aux griffes de qui" just doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer below. "Aux" indicates the complement of "arracher", so it's "arracher aux/des griffes de la foule", and that IMHO would require "desquelles", referring to "griffes" not to "la foule".

Comment: I'm pretty sure :-)

Comment: @Frank There seems to be something true in your comment: the pronoun (« qui ») would not have the right form. I have been thinking about it, but I am not too sure and it'll take me some time before I come up with an answer.

Comment: Maybe something to check in the Grevisse. But Graffito also hesitated. When native french speakers read that sentence, I think they stumble on that "qui".

Comment: @Frank As the answer to your comment is long and as it adds something to my post, I am making it part of it as an addition (One detail, however: your reason for not finding « qui » correct is an error; the antecedent of « qui » is « foule »: « …cette foule aux griffes et aux crocs de LAQUELLE FOULE les petits doigts…».)

Comment: maybe, after all, but see Segorian's other example: "Savez-vous pourquoi cette foule, de qui l’attitude vous étonne...". J'aurais écrit, sans aucune hésitation: "Savez-vous pourquoi cette foule, _dont_ l’attitude vous étonne...".

Comment: Maybe you are right, and then "cette foule aux griffes et aux crocs de LAQUELLE" would sound better.

Comment: @Frank « Cette foule, dont l’attitude » is the best choice (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foule+de+qui%2Cfoule+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: I know, that's what I was saying, but Mirbeau seems to insist on using "de qui", which is leading me to think that "de qui" had some legitimacy in his time in the 2 situations we have in this thread.

Comment: The ngrams stats are actually revealing: there is a small bump for "de qui" around 1900, which is around the time Mirbeau was writing! So this would confirm my suspicion that in that period, "de qui" was more used in those situations.

Comment: "La foule étaient parti(e)s", plural, would be strict grammar error. It would be corrected in school without question.

Answer (score 2):

The word *qui* refers to the crowd.

The sentence as a whole is to be understood metaphorically. The words *griffes* and *crocs* tell us that the people in the street have started to behave like wild animals, hungry for human flesh. Those very words—*chair humaine*—refer to the beggar, saved from carnivorous beasts by the woman whose purse he attempted to steal.

The woman's fingers are contrasted with the claws and fangs of the agitated crowd, and are described as “small” to emphasise the importance of her gesture. Finally, placing the word *humaine* last serves to further accentuate the message of the story, namely that benevolence should always prevail over animalistic tendencies.

Answer (score 2):

That "de qui" feels weird here. It can only refer to the "foule", but it still sounds strange.

If we put the sentence in a more straightforward order, we get

> un peu de chair humaine vient d'être arrachée, par les petits doigts d'une femme, des griffes et des crocs de cette foule.

"Aux" clearly indicates the complement of the verb "arracher". I believe the following simplifications show the structure of the sentence:

> les petits doigts arrachent aux griffes et aux crocs de la foule

or

> les petits doigts arrachent *des* griffes et *des* crocs de la foule

I think the following flows better:

> poursuivie par les huées de cette foule aux griffes et aux crocs *de laquelle* les petits doigts d’une femme venaient d’arracher un peu de chair humaine.

**Note**: I have changed my previous answer in agreement with LPH's comment. "laquelle" referring to the "foule" feels better here, rather than "qui".

Comment: — It seems to me that we should not be trying to correct the author's text but rather to make sense of it. (Mirbeau is known for many things, but not, I believe, for having a poor grasp of French grammar.) As you point out, _de qui_ doesn't work well grammatically with _griffes_ and _crocs_. Accordingly, it must refer to (the people in) the crowd. We might translate: “…the crowd, all claws and fangs, from which the slight fingers of a woman…”.

Comment: Of course, Mirbeau can write whatever he wants, but as I was saying, it took Graffito also some time to figure out, which to me indicates that this construction is grating somehow.

Comment: @Segorian I don't disagree with you, and I have inflicted my answer accordingly.

Comment: — It's worth mentioning, perhaps, that Mirbeau paid particular attention to crowds and their behaviour, treating “la foule” almost as a person. This may have influenced his choice of words. For comparison, the following is from his _En écoutant la rue_ (my emphasis):
“Savez-vous pourquoi **cette foule, de qui** l’attitude vous étonne, cette foule prête à toutes les extravagances, à tous les emballements, reste calme dans son ivresse et pacifique dans ses hurlements ?”

Comment: Your reasoning does not correspond to reality.

Comment: @LPH “Your reasoning does not correspond to reality.“ If this is a reply to my comment, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Segorian No, this is a comment intended for user Frank, and it is meant as a comment on his (I suppose "his" legitimate here) post.

Comment: @Segorian Encore plus étrange - j'écrirais sans hésitation: "Savez-vous pourquoi cette foule, _dont_ l’attitude vous étonne...". Ce "de qui" semble encore plus mal placé. Je me demande si c'est une vieille tournure, ou une tournure spécifique a cet auteur, ou à une région?

Comment: @LPH not sure what you mean?

Comment: @LPH I agree with you, in fact, and I have changed my answer.